# Any routine in NumPy where we stack the columns (except the 1st) one below other repeating the elements of 1st column for those columns

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

The '**array1**' consist of 10 rows and 3 columns. arry1.shape = [10,3]

```
array1 = np.array([['Ship.0001.a', -1.52279114723206, 1.52279114723206],
 ['Ship.0002.b', -1.64301979541779, 3.64257907867432],
 ['Ship.0033.g', -35055.33, 35055.33],
 ['Ship.0004.d', -3723.0254, 50663.02],
 ['Cross.0010.a', -53728.453125, 53728.453125],
 ['Cross.0002.e', -4512.5186, 39713.844],
 ['Cross.0033.c', -25680.36, 25680.36],
 ['Cross.0004.d', -0.893001675605774, 0.684107720851898],
 ['Fluid.00010.a', -1.3819944858551, 1.3819944858551],
 ['Fluid.0012.d', -1.53111243247986, 3.5307240486145]])
```

I want to create an output array of **arry2.shape** = [20,3] which is shown below. Just want to know is there any function/routine to do soo.

```
arry2 = [['Ship.0001.a', -1.52279114723206],
         ['Ship.0001.a', 1.52279114723206],
         ['Ship.0002.b', -1.64301979541779],
         ['Ship.0002.b', 3.64257907867432]
         ['Ship.0033.g', -35055.33],
         ['Ship.0033.g', 35055.33],
         ['Ship.0004.d', -3723.0254],
         ['Ship.0004.d', 50663.02],
         ['Cross.0010.a', -53728.453125],
         ['Cross.0010.a',  53728.453125],
         ['Cross.0002.e', -4512.5186],
         ['Cross.0002.e', 39713.844],
         ['Cross.0033.c', -25680.36],
         ['Cross.0033.c', 25680.36],
         ['Cross.0004.d', -0.893001675605774],
         ['Cross.0004.d', 0.684107720851898],
         ['Fluid.00010.a', -1.3819944858551],
         ['Fluid.00010.a', 1.3819944858551],
         ['Fluid.0012.d', -1.53111243247986],
         ['Fluid.0012.d' 3.5307240486145]]
```

Please take a note, the actually array is huge hence I am looking for the a routine which provides  the result as fast as possible.

Comment: How about `array1[:, [0, 1, 0, 2]].reshape(-1, 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = np.hstack([array1[:, [0,1]], array1[:, [0,2]]]).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Or, similartly but probably better, as suggested in comment by @MechanicPig:

```
out = array1[:, [0, 1, 0, 2]].reshape(-1, 2)
```

##### arbitrary number of columns

stack all but the first one:

```
out = np.hstack([np.repeat(array1[:, 0], array1.shape[1]-1)[:,None],
                 array1[:, 1:].reshape(-1, 1)])
```

output:

```
array([['Ship.0001.a', '-1.52279114723206'],
       ['Ship.0001.a', '1.52279114723206'],
       ['Ship.0002.b', '-1.64301979541779'],
       ['Ship.0002.b', '3.64257907867432'],
       ['Ship.0033.g', '-35055.33'],
       ['Ship.0033.g', '35055.33'],
       ['Ship.0004.d', '-3723.0254'],
       ['Ship.0004.d', '50663.02'],
       ['Cross.0010.a', '-53728.453125'],
       ['Cross.0010.a', '53728.453125'],
       ['Cross.0002.e', '-4512.5186'],
       ['Cross.0002.e', '39713.844'],
       ['Cross.0033.c', '-25680.36'],
       ['Cross.0033.c', '25680.36'],
       ['Cross.0004.d', '-0.893001675605774'],
       ['Cross.0004.d', '0.684107720851898'],
       ['Fluid.00010.a', '-1.3819944858551'],
       ['Fluid.00010.a', '1.3819944858551'],
       ['Fluid.0012.d', '-1.53111243247986'],
       ['Fluid.0012.d', '3.5307240486145']], dtype='<U32')
```